# Solve differential equations with an initial condition in the form of a limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I want to solve the following differential equation

[image]

with the initial condition

[image]

This is known as the [Bunch-Davies vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Davies_vacuum), and the above are equations (4.1) and (3.37) from [this paper](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/TEACHING/ICTP/QFTinDS.pdf)

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
eq = {y''[t] + (k^2 - 2/t) y[t] == 0, y[-∞] == Exp[I*k*t], y'[-∞] == 0};
NDSolve[eq, y[t], t]
```

However, I do not know how to input this initial condition in NDSolve.

Thanks!

---

Please let write my equation in the new form:

```
 eq = {y''[t] + (k^2 - 2/t) y[t] == 0, y[-\[Infinity]] == Exp[I*k*t], y'[-\      [Infinity]] == 0};
 NDSolve[eq, y[t], t]
```

How can solve this one?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: In your initial condition, isn't `t` equal to `0`? If so, then it would be `y[0] = 1`

Comment: No, in fact t is not equal to 0.

Comment: @mzar, sorry if I am being dense, but you are solving for `y[t]`, right?  So what, then, does `y[0]` mean if not the value of `y` when `t` is equal to 0?

Comment: So let's consider this initial condition: y[-\[Infinity]]=E^(-I k t)

Comment: @mzar - that still doesn't make sense to me.  When you say `y[-Infinity]`, that means you have set the variable `t` equal to minus infinity.  So then the right hand side of that equation you wrote should not have a t in it.

Comment: this is known as Bunch–Davies vacuum.

Comment: Please see the following paper http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/TEACHING/ICTP/QFTinDS.pdf,  I wand to solve for example Eq. 4.1 **numerically**  with initial condition 3.37.

Comment: Aha, so what you have is a limiting form for the behavior as `t` goes to infinity!  That makes more sense  :-)

Comment: @mzar - you had a typo in your equation, you didn't square the `t` in the denominator.  Using `DSolve[y''[t] + (k^2 - 2/t^2) y[t] == 0, y[t], t]` will at least give you a wave equation solution, though you may need to apply the limits yourself.  If you want to use `NDSolve`, then you need to give a value for `k`

Comment: Thank you very much, in my case the square is not important. For the case of k, we can fix it to be k=0.01.

Comment: @mzar - the square most certainly is important, as without it you don't get a wave equation as the solution, but with it you do.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting few elementary syntax errors you might try this:

```
 eq = {y''[t] + (k^2 - 2/t) y[t] == 0, y[0] == Exp[I*k*t], y'[0] == 0};
DSolve[eq, y[t], t]

(* 
{{y[t] -> -E^(-Sqrt[k^2] t + (-Sqrt[-k^2] + Sqrt[k^2]) t) t C[
     1] (Hypergeometric1F1[
        1 + (-4 Sqrt[k^2] - 2 (-2 - 2 Sqrt[k^2]))/(4 Sqrt[-k^2]), 2, 
        2 Sqrt[-k^2] t] HypergeometricU[
        1 + (-4 Sqrt[k^2] - 2 (-2 - 2 Sqrt[k^2]))/(4 Sqrt[-k^2]), 2, 
        0] - HypergeometricU[
       1 + (-4 Sqrt[k^2] - 2 (-2 - 2 Sqrt[k^2]))/(4 Sqrt[-k^2]), 2, 
       2 Sqrt[-k^2] t])}}

*)
```

with a warninhg: "Unable to resolve some of the arbitrary constants in the general solution using the given boundary conditions....". The warning indicates that the initial conditions should be chosen more carefully.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to use the NDSolve not DSolve. As well as, is it possible to extend it to the parametricNDSolve and then for example plot y in terms of k?

Comment: @mzar, keep in mind that the solution here is contradictory to the initial conditions you gave.  If you substitute `t=0` in the solution here, it gives 0.

Comment: So let's consider this initial condition: y[-\[Infinity]]=E^(-I k t)

Comment: @mzar Keep also in mind that the above solutionwas unable to resolve an arbitrary constant. As I already have written something here is wrong either with the equation or with the initial conditions. To plot it you (1) need to fix this constant/initial condition question and (2) you cannot plot a complex function straightforwardly. You need then think, what precisely would you like to plot? And this is up to you, not up to me. Or, otherwise, you need to fix somehow a real initial condition. It is again up to you.

Comment: @mzar  By the way, in a hurry I did not noticed that the initial condition is formulated incorrectly: how is it that it depends upon `t` in your case?

Comment: I fact I want to plot the absolute value of y in terms of k.

Comment: @mzar Your initial condition is incorrect.

Comment: do you meant y[-[Infinity]]=E^(-I k t) is incorrect?

Comment: @mzar  I mean it cannot depend upon t: it is initial, that is, taken at `t=0` .